is there a way of solving; TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable in django?
I am a beginner learning Django. While doing my project, I encountered an error and now am stuck.
While running 'python manage.py makemigrations', the error below occured:
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable

Where can I start to solve the problem?
This is my code:
myapp/views.py

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Book, UserBook
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
# Create your views here.


def home(request):
    books = Book.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'books': books})

def library(request):
    user_books = UserBook.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'library.html', {'user_books': user_books})

def add_book(request, book_id):
    book = Book.objects.get(id=book_id)
    user_book = UserBook.objects.create(user=request.user, book=book)
    return redirect('library')

myapp/urls.py
'''Defines the urls for the library application'''

from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'library'
urlpatterns = [
    #homepage
    path('', views.index, name='home'),
    path('library/', views.library, name='library'),
    path('add_book/<int:book_id>/', views.add_book, name='add_book'),
]

traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/in/.local/share/virtualenvs/ArenaStudy-g4tNO7nf/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 740, in url_patterns
    iter(patterns)
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/in/Desktop/ArenaStudy/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/in/Desktop/ArenaStudy/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/in/.local/share/virtualenvs/ArenaStudy-g4tNO7nf/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/in/.local/share/virtualenvs/ArenaStudy-g4tNO7nf/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/inn/.local/share/virtualenvs/ArenaStudy-g4tNO7nf/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 413, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/inn/.local/share/virtualenvs/ArenaStudy-g4tNO7nf/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 454, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/Users/inn/.local/share/virtualenvs/ArenaStudy-g4tNO7nf/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 486, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/Users/inn/.local/share/virtualenvs/ArenaStudy-g4tNO7nf/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/Users/inno/.local/share/virtualenvs/ArenaStudy-g4tNO7nf/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/Users/inno/.local/share/virtualenvs/ArenaStudy-g4tNO7nf/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/Users/inno/.local/share/virtualenvs/ArenaStudy-g4tNO7nf/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 520, in check
    messages.extend(check_resolver(pattern))
  File "/Users/inn/.local/share/virtualenvs/ArenaStudy-g4tNO7nf/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/Users/inn/.local/share/virtualenvs/ArenaStudy-g4tNO7nf/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 519, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/Users/inno/.local/share/virtualenvs/ArenaStudy-g4tNO7nf/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 47, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/inno/.local/share/virtualenvs/ArenaStudy-g4tNO7nf/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 748, in url_patterns
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name)) from e
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<module 'library' from '/Users/inno/Desktop/ArenaStudy/library/__init__.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see the 'urlpatterns' variable with valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

myapp/models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    grade = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    book_cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    published_date = models.DateField()
    allowed_users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='allowed_books')

    @classmethod
    def add_book(cls, title, author, published_date):
    #Create a new book instance
        new_book = cls(title=title, author=author, published_date=published_date,)
        # Save the new book instance to the database
        new_book.save()
        return new_book

    def delete_book(self):
        '''delete the book instance from the database'''
        self.delete()

class UserBook(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    current = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)

I have tried getting some answers online but i have not gotten any clear way to solve the problem

Please, [edit] the question and share the full traceback as code (not an image). Normally the Django error page has a function to turn the error in a text format that includes settings, traceback, etc.

When writing a question, please split the files and the output into different snippets so it's easier to read and understand.
About your question, the error you're facing is this one:
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<module 'library' from '/Users/inno/Desktop/ArenaStudy/library/__init__.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see the 'urlpatterns' variable with valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import. 
Since you have a urlpatterns variable with valid patterns, the error is probably because of a circular import.
Try changing
from . import views

to something like
from .views import index, library, add_book

and see if that fixes the issue.
Hope this helps!

Your code:
myapp/urls.py
'''Defines the urls for the library application'''

from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'library'
urlpatterns = [
    #homepage
    path('', views.index, name='home'),
    path('library/', views.library, name='library'),
    path('add_book/<int:book_id>/', views.add_book, name='add_book'),
]

Correct Code:
myapp/urls.py
'''Defines the urls for the library application'''

from django.urls import path
from myapp.views import index, library, add_book


app_name = 'library'
urlpatterns = [
    #homepage
    path('', index, name='home'),
    path('library/', library, name='library'),
    path('add_book/<int:book_id>/', add_book, name='add_book'),
]


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
